# If I update my iPhone 4S from iOS 6.1. to iOS 6.1.2 - will it crash?

Tags: iphone, ios

Are updates like this reliable?
Should I update? Will I get crashes and stuff if I update? :/ iOS newb.

Comment: Of course you should update. No, it won't crash anything.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to answer this question. While it is safe to assume that Apple tries to ensure stable upgrade procedures there always is the slight chance that your phone may crash during the upgrade due to specific issues/software constellations with your specific phone.

Comment: I have been running iOS since 2.0 and have updated to every single new revision. I have never had any issues related to instability as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not jailbroken, it is perfectly safe to upgrade. If anything, 6.1.2 will crash less than 6.1 because of the bug fixes.